# gnuplot: transform axis of matrix plot with "every"

Tags: gnuplot

I have a problem with plotting matrices with gnuplot. I am plotting one row of matrix with `every` option like that

```
plot inputfile matrix every 1:1:(4+N*M+1):100:(4+N*(M+1)):100 with linespoint
```

where 100 is number of row. It gave me that nearly good result:

[image]

I would like to get xrange from 0 to 360, but when I use something like that

```
plot inputfile matrix using ($1*11.25):2 every 1:1:(4+N*M+1):100:(4+N*(M+1)):100 with linespoint
```

it doesen't work: wrong result

[image]

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide data, so I create some for the following example.
As I understand you want to plot a certain row of a matrix and adjust the x-range.
Check `help matrix every`.

For example, in `plot FILE u 1:2:3 matrix`, `1` is the column, `2` the row and `3` is the (z)-value.
And in `plot FILE u 1:3 matrix every ::c:r:c:r`, `c` is the column and `r` is the row (counting starts from `0`).
So the example below plots the 4th row and the x-range is adjusted from 0 to 360.

**Code:**

```
### plotting a certain row while adjusting the x-range
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2  3  4  5  6  7  8
3  4  5  6  7  8  9
4  5  6  7  8  9 10
5  6  7  8  9 10 11
EOD

set key top left
plot $Data u ($1*60):3 matrix every :::3::3 w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Problem was in an order of `using`, `matrix` and `every`. Right order is just like that.

Comment: @vs_nikolaev `plot $Data matrix u ($1*60):3 every :::3::3` should also work. I guess your mistake was `using ($1*11.25):2` instead of `using ($1*11.25):3`.

Comment: Oooo, maybe! I will check. For my regret, i missed explanation of  `u 1:2:3` for matrix